# Is there any way to open a file using a diff without patching the original?

Tags: file, file-io, diff, patch, file-handling

Example, I have a 40Mb file, and i want to make some minor changes to it, maybe 20Kb of changes.

I can create a diff between the resulting file and the original, simply enough, either by writing it manually with the application that is making the change, or by taking both the original file and the resulting file and generating the diff from that (using Rabin's polynomial fingerprinting algorithm for example)...

The issue is, in order to read the effective outcome of that diff (the new file), I have to patch the diff to the original and create the resulting new file and read that... this creates 2 40mb files with only 20kb of difference between them.  It seems logical that one could use the initial file combined with the diff and parse (for reading anyway) the resulting final file without having to create a whole new copy of it.

I have looked through xdiff and it has the functions to create a diff given 2 files, or to apply a diff as a patch to a file, but none to get a simple file handle when provided with the original file and a diff file.

Does such a thing exist?  It would be tremendously helpful for storage space savings on larger files, even if only for read-only (write operations could write to a new diff, possibly).

Examples in any language would be fine, although c, python or php would be great if readily available.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using TortoiseMerge to View Diffs:

You could use TortoiseMerge to view the diff without creating a patch.

Here's an [overview](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) of what that looks like.  I am also attaching the [guide](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/help-onepage.html) and a [download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/Tools/1.6.7/).  If that doesn't suit you, here is a great list of [alternative diff tools](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html#tsvn-dug-diff-tools).

#### Further Consideration:

Depending on how often you are making changes and your interest in file size savings you may want to consider using a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) (perhaps you do already).  Common options include [SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/svn/info), [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info), and [Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mercurial/info).

Answer (score 0):

What your are describing is a source code control with delta storage: you store many versions of a file, and delta are saved, then you can request entire files which are recomposed on the fly, so you can choose to access them directly (for example with the appropriate lib), or save locally before access.

Search for Subversion, git, mercurial and so on, how they implement their delta storage and you'll have working examples. Git has a maintenance task to do that internally, using delta storage when it considers it profitable. Git is in programmed in C.

Clearly it will give a sample of how to access sequentially this kind of files. Once you've got that composing patches is relatively simple, and if the patch commands list can be accessed efficiently you can as well build a random-access solution (as long as the literal part of the patch and the original are accessible).